# Sharepoint like Edit a document in Microsoft Word using ASP.NET - Office Integration

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I am working on a document management project and client wants to edit a document just like how one can do in sharepoint. So when a user click edit document in word and makes modification and saves, it should save on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: licensing issues and some other requirements that will involve outside company customers etc

Answer (score 1):

For Word, I would use a third part UI control like [this one](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/products/dotnetserver/overview/).